# Unable to display String values after splitting

Tags: java

I was writing a sample code that splits a given string based on the delimiter and displays the final set of strings. Here is my code-

```
        String[] arr = null;
        String[] newArr = null;
        String strArr = "adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg$$$$$";
        for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length(); i++) {
            newArr = strArr.split("\\$\\$\\$\\$");
            for (int j = 0; j < newArr.length; j++) {
                arr = newArr[j].split("\\$\\$");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(strArr);
        System.out.println(newArr[0]);
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
        System.out.println(arr[1]); // throwing exception here
        System.out.println(arr[2]);
        System.out.println(arr[3]);
```

And this is the output I got-

```
adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg$$$$$
adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at ArraySplit.main(ArraySplit.java:20)
```

This is the output i was expecting-

```
$adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg$$$$$
$adg$dgsd$$brr$dhr$$ce$twt$$dttgdf$gdfg
$adg$dgsd
$brr$dhr
$ce$twt
$dttgdf$gdfg$
```

What I observed was, if there are 2 $ signs, since its the same as the delimiter pattern, it works fine. But as there are 3 $ signs in between, I am not able to display the rest of the String objects. Any idea on how to tackle this? (extra info: I am actually using this as part of passing a part of the string as password in PostGreSQL)

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You want to split string with $?

Comment: I want to split string with "$$". I'll update with my expected output now.

Comment: `strArr.length()` is > `1`. so `arr1,arr2,..` are overridden from `newArr[1].replace` and `newArr[1]` is only `'$'`

Comment: What's the use of the loop with `ì`? Simply leave it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg$$$$$

The original array.

> adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg

$$$$ as a delimeter, so the elements of the newArray will be: adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg and $ (You have 5 $ in your string)

> $

In the last loop, newArr[j] will be $, the split will generate a single-element array, which contains a $. So arr[0] is $.

> $
>
> $
>
> $

Same as above. Obviously a OutOfBoundsException.

I think the key to this problem is to understand the [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) itself. Take a look at the docs.

The following code will generate a similar output to your expected result:

```
String strArr = "$adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg$$$$$";
//Print out the string
System.out.println(strArr);
String newArr = strArr.replaceAll("\\$\\$\\$\\$\\$", "");
System.out.println(newArr);
String[] arr = newArr.split("\\$\\$");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why an outOfBoundsException.There will be none such. As you say string is split into substrings:adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg and $.So last loop that second loop will set all arr0,arr1,arr2,arr3 to $.

Comment: The last iteration of the nested loop will be arr = newArr[1].split("\\$\\$"), where the newArr[1] is $. Then the returned arr will be a single-element array. So arr[1] will incur an OutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Nope, see my answer below. Nested loop will run twice since it split call return an array of two strings.Also in the nested loop there is no call to split, it is replace.

Comment: No, he has already updated his code. Now it is split, not a replace.

Answer (score 1):

The result you can see is the status of the `arr`s **after the last cycle run**.

Perhaps you want to print them **in the cycle**.

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "$adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg$$$$$";
String toArray = text.replaceAll("[\\$]{4}", "");
String[] result = toArray.split("[\\$]{2}");

// just printing
System.out.println(text);
System.out.println(toArray);
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(result[i]);
}
```

Comment: What difference does that make?

Answer (score 0):

A $ sign is reserved for matching end of line. You are searching for literal '$' using \$ expression.
So your expression will split the string into part:

```
adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg$$$$$ =  "adg$dgsd$$$brr$dhr$$$ce$twt$$$dttgdf$gdfg" + "$"
```

Splitted by the occurence of **$$$$**

Second loop will overwrite all arr0,arr1,arr2,arr3 to $, the second splitted string.
Obviously Your replace call will not do any thing as there is no match for $$ in the second splitted string.